# Jest takes more time if jest.config.js is in subfolder or subdirectory

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

I have a project **hosted**, it contains jest.config.js, node modules, package.json
If i run **npm run test** with this structure it will take less time.

```
hosted
 -jest.config.js
 -package.json
 -node_moduels
 -babel.config.js
 -.babelrc
```

But as i had to manage two project with same directory i created another folder named **self-hosted** moved all the common config files to root and handled both from root. Now if i run **npm run test** it takes almost **double time**. FYI I have not add any testcases in self-hosted folder.

```
hosted
 -jest.config.js
self-hosted
 -jest.config.js
package.json
node_modules
babel.config.js
.babelrc
```

Answer (score 0):

In my jest.config.js i used **transformIgnorePatterns** which was causing testcase to take almost double the time.
Maybe wrong pattern inside it might be causing issue.